# Cloud Convert job error "started too many jobs at once"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cloudconvert

I'm sending files to a php script from an html form. In the php script, I'm getting the temp file location and trying to convert it from a jpg to png. I'm getting this error from the server when trying to convert the file:

> CloudConvert\Exceptions\HttpClientException: You have started too many
> jobs at once in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\photocloud\vendor\cloudconvert\cloudconvert-php\src\Exceptions\HttpClientException

upload.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \CloudConvert\CloudConvert;
use \CloudConvert\Models\Job;
use \CloudConvert\Models\ImportUploadTask;
use \CloudConvert\Models\Task;

$obj_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$obj_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$obj_errors = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$obj_checksum = md5_file($obj_temp, false);
$obj_size = filesize($obj_temp);
$obj_extention = strtolower(pathinfo($obj_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$cloudconvert = new CloudConvert([
    'api_key' => 'my_key_here',
    'sandbox' => false
]);

$obj_key = $obj_checksum.'.'.$obj_extention;

$job = (new Job())
->addTask(new Task('import/upload','upload-my-file'))
->addTask(
    (new Task('convert', 'convert-my-file'))
        ->set('input', 'upload-my-file')
        ->set('output_format', 'png')
)
->addTask(
    (new Task('export/url', 'export-my-file'))
        ->set('input', 'convert-my-file')
);

$cloudconvert->jobs()->create($job);
$url_task = $job->getTasks()->whereName('export-my-file')[0];
$cloudconvert->tasks()->upload($url_task, fopen($obj_temp, 'r'), 'test.png');
$cloudconvert->jobs()->wait($job);
foreach ($job->getExportUrls() as $file) {
    echo $file->url;
}
```

upload.js

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector('.upload');

$.each(fileInput.files, function(index, val) {
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileInput.files[index]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload.php',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```